# Как совершить поиск по двум файлам, игнорируя первые 10 символов

Tags: python

Есть код, который считывает из второго файла номера строк (STR-......) и по этим номерам ищет совпадение в первом файле и удаляет найденные.

Нужно изменить код так, чтобы номера строк (то есть первые 10 символов) игнорировались, поиск совершать по тексту, который идёт после 10 символов. Подскажите, как реализовать? Пробовал выставить [10:] - не помогло

```
with open("file1.txt", "r") as file, \
     open("file2.txt", "r") as file2, \
     open("file_done.txt", "w") as rezult:
 
    lines2 = set(line.strip() for line in file2)

    for line in file:
        if line[:10] not in lines2:
            rezult.write(line)
```

Содержимое file1:

```
STR-111111Я вас любил: любовь еще, быть может,
STR-222222В душе моей угасла не совсем;
```

Содержимое file2:

```
STR-333333Я вас любил: любовь еще, быть может,
```

Результат нужен такой:

```
STR-222222В душе моей угасла не совсем;
```

Номера строк в первом и втором файле не совпадают, поэтому надо искать только по тексту, который следует после номера и до конца строки.

Comment: Может у `line` тоже `strip` надо делать?

Comment: Я вам уже советовал - сделайте print полученного словаря. Вдруг там не то, чего вы ждёте.

Comment: `set(line.strip() for line in file2)` -> `set(line.strip()[10:] for line in file2)`, `if line[:10] not in lines2:` -> `if line.strip()[10:] not in lines2:`

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy спасибо 

Comment: @Alexander Разве об этом не говорилоcь в прошлой теме?

Comment: @MBo я видимо где-то ошибку допускал

Answer (score 2):

Вы пытаетесь сравнить последние 10 строк в каждой строке со строками в `file2.txt` :

```py
lines2 = set(line.strip() for line in file2)
...
    if line[:10] not in lines2:
```

Но можно обрезать первые 10 строк во всех файлах и проверять их схожесть.

```py
lines2 = set(line.strip()[10:] for line in file2)
...
    if line.strip()[10:] not in lines2:
```

Полный пример рабочего кода:

```py
with open("file1.txt", "r") as file, \
     open("file2.txt", "r") as file2, \
     open("file_done.txt", "w") as rezult:
    
    lines2 = set(line.strip()[10:] for line in file2)
    
    for line in file:
        if line.strip()[10:] not in lines2:
            rezult.write(line)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы в первом и втором файле игнорировались знаки препинания? Во втором файле есть много предложений, которые отличаются от предложений из первого файла только запятой/точкой/другим_символом и их тоже нужно учесть. Буду благодарен!